# Tori of revolution in $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

The motivation of this question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398148/parametrization-of-tori-in-mathbbs3), where I asked about some kind of *general parametrization* for tori in $\mathbb{S}^3$.

Apparently not even the parametrization that I included in that question for tori in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is valid, as it was suggested in one answer. Therefore it looks very unlikely to find what I was asking for. Thus, I wonder if at least it is possible to **construct tori of revolution in $\mathbb{S}^3$** by considering some smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^4$ like
\begin{align}
 C:I&\subset\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^4\\
 &t\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ f(t)\\ g(t) \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
for some $f,g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with the condition
$$f^2(t)+g^2(t)=1$$
to ensure that the curve is in $\mathbb{S}^3$ and rotate this curve in $\mathbb{R}^4$ by multiplying it by some rotational matrix of $\mathrm{SO}(4)$.

**Questions**:

Is this method valid to produce tori of revolution in $\mathbb{S}^3$ in a *general* way? (By general I just mean depending on the choice of functions $f$ and $g$ that define the generatrix curve). Or maybe should I also restrict this choice to closed curves?

Comment: How general can it be? Your requirement $f^2+g^2=1$ seems to leave only one possible curve up to reparametrization.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I am not sure why is that... Could you please give me an argument/idea? Anyways, even if it's not that *general*, applying the rotation would I get a torus in $\mathbb{S}^3$?