# Imitating in $\mathbb{R}^4$ the construction of tori in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

This question belongs to a series of questions that keep arising in my mind from time to time: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398148/285940) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414174/285940) are (in order) the two questions that I asked before.

The aim of the first question, let's say finding a similar "parametric definition" that was conformal for tori in $\mathbb{S}^3$ as that one in $\mathbb{R}^3$, was apparently too optimistic. Not even what I thought was a "parametric definition" in $\mathbb{R}^3$ seemed to be correct in the answer I got. Then I asked in the second question if it was possible to start with a closed curve and by rotating it construct a torus in $\mathbb{S}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^4$. I didn't get answers to this question.

At this point I'd like just to understand the most basic ideas. The parametric definition in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of a torus comes from a construction using a circle and rotating it. Suppose I start with a circle
$$(x-a)^2+z^2=r^2,$$
for some fixed $a>r>0$.

Parametrizing this curve and multipliying the parametric vector by a matrix like
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0\\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
we rotate the curve around the $z$-axis (visually is easy to see that we construct in this way a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and the usual parametric definition that one can find in the literature is obtained.

Now I'd like to imitate this idea but in $\mathbb{R}^4$. So I start with the same circle $(x-a)^2+z^2=r^2$, I take a parametrization
$$x=r\cos\theta+a$$
$$z=r\sin\theta,$$
where $r\in(0,a)$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Now I rotate it by doing
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0 & 0\\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta+a\\ 0\\ r\sin\theta\\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi(r\cos\theta+a)\\ \sin\phi(r\cos\theta+a)\\ r\sin\theta\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

This construction is exactly the same as that one in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which makes sense completely. Because of this I see that my simple question should be:

**What is a torus** (not topologically, that is clear) **in $\mathbb{R}^4$? And once that's clear, what would be the analogous process to 'fit' a torus in $\mathbb{R}^4$?** From there should be easy to understand how would it be in $\mathbb{S}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I'd say that without further context most people would take the definition of *torus* to be the topological one, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for when you ask "What is a torus in $\Bbb R^4$?"

Comment: As for the second question, there is a standard embedding of the $2$-torus (i.e., $S^1 \times S^1$) in $\Bbb S^3 \subset \Bbb R^4$, namely $\{(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) \in \Bbb R^4 : x_1^2 + y_1^2 = \frac{1}{2} = x_2^2 + y_2^2 \}$, or better yet, $\{(z, w) \in \Bbb C^2 : |z| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = |w| \}$. This is a *Clifford torus*, which is distinguished among topological tori in $\Bbb R^4$ by having zero curvature.

Comment: @Travis Ok, maybe refrasing: if we can say that $((a+r\cos \theta )\cos {\varphi }, (a+r\cos \theta )\sin {\varphi }, r\sin \theta)$ defines a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$, what parametrization defines a torus in $\mathbb{R}^4$? (if there's such a thing). And (again, if there's such a thing) is there a similar way to get this parametrization to that one I mentioned for the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case?

Comment: Again, I don't know precisely what you *mean* by torus in $\Bbb R^4$. An embedding of $S^1 \times S^1$? $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$? Both of these are possible, but these are both topological definitions. (NB it's possible to embed the first into $S^3$ but not the second.)

Comment: @Travis Ok, so I think the idea to answer my question would be based on all these comments: $S^1\times S^1$ is a torus embedded in $\mathbb{S}^3$ and $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ is a torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ but, apart from the Clifford torus, they can't be described by a general parametrization like we do in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: No, there are many (topological) (2-)tori in $\Bbb S^3$, and many of these have straightforward parameterizations. For example, the explicit Clifford torus I mentioned can be parameterized by $(\alpha, \beta) \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha, \cos \beta, \sin \beta)$.

Comment: @Travis Right, thank you. Now I'd be really satisfied if it was right to say that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ there's only one (topological) torus and that's why we can describe all of them with just one parametrization...

Comment: No, there are many (topological) tori in $\Bbb R^3$---that is, topological embeddings $S^1 \times S^1 \to \Bbb R^3$, many (most) of which do not have simple explicit formulae. Just take your favorite torus with the usual parameterization and deform part of it a little without changing the topology. In order to get a nice result along the lines of "we can describe them all" for geometric objects, usually what we're describing all of needs to have stronger information than the topology alone entails.

Comment: @Travis Ok, thank you. Then, last question I promise, the statement "a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is defined in parametric equations by...", is simply false or incomplete, right? As you said, not all tori can be written explicitly with that expression and therefore my idea of doing the same in $\mathbb{R}^4$ was wrong in the first place...

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the statement. It's correct to say that the parameterization (with specific fixed $a, r$) defines a torus in $\Bbb R^3$, but it's not true that every toplogically embedded torus in $\Bbb R^3$ can be parameterized that way for some $a, r$.

Comment: @Travis Exactly. That I meant by 'icomplete'. Really appreciate all of your comments. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found them useful!

Answer (score 1):

This construction can never produce a torus in $\mathbb{S}^{3}_{r}$ for any $r>0$. Since rotations with centre $0$ act on $\mathbb{S}^{3}_{r}$, the torus you construct will be contained in $\mathbb{S}^{3}_{r}$ if and only if the original circle is. The circle contains the points $(a-r,0,0,0)$ and $(a+r,0,0,0)$, which have different distance from the origin, so this is not the case.

(Notation: $\mathbb{S^{3}}_{r} = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^{4} : v \cdot v = r^2\}$)

Edit: case $a = 0$.  in this case the point $(0,0,r,0)$ is fixed by the rotation, so the space you obtain is not homeomorphic to torus. In fact the space you obtain is homeomorphic to a $2$-sphere.

The standard way to embed a torus in $\mathbb{S}^{3} \subset \mathbb{C}^{2}$ is by the equaction $|z_{1}|^2 = |z_{2}|^{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ this is the so called Clifford torus. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus.

Comment: In the case of $r=1$ and $a=0$ the parametric vector clearly would be in $\mathbb{S}^3$, but firstly I'd like to actually understand why this does **not** (or maybe yes?) define a torus in $\mathbb{R}^4$...

Comment: If this is the case you are interested in then why did you include the parameter $a$? Anyway, I will edit my answer  to include this case

Comment: No. As the question illustrates I'm interested firstly on understanding 'what is a torus in $\mathbb{R}^4$', since the construction I'm using just gives me the same torus as in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but in a greater dimension... The parameter $a$ appears in the definition that one can usually find for a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ constructed by rotating the curve around an axis. Understanding how to fit a torus in $\mathbb{S}^3$ would come later.

Comment: For $a \neq 0$ it is possible to obtain a torus in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, I am not a aware of any way to "fit" this into the 3-sphere that would be geometric somehow.  I think that Clifford Tori are definitely relevant to understanding the question "what is a torus in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$". Anyway, I hope this helped in some way.